# сбор данных с разных датчиков

Tags: автоматизация

Задались вопросом автоматизации процесса производства у себя на предприятии.

На данный момент перед нашим отделом стоит следующая задача:

1. Сбор данных с разных датчиков по всему технологическому процессу ( сюда входят как аналоговые данные так и цифровые)
2. Компоновка этих данных и их передача на удаленный сервер
3. там данные обрабатываются и на выходе выдают необходимые параметры
4. вывод этих параметров непосредственно на предприятии

Вопрос следующий : Какое оборудование и программное обеспечение необходимо использовать для реализации данного проекта? Если можете назвать марку и модель необходимого оборудования будет просто здорово!

Данные необходимо форматировать в формат json или Xml

Comment: Добавьте конкретики. Какие у вас датчики? Какие расстояния от датчиков до объектов инфраструктуры связи? Имеются ли технологические сети?

Пока что вам можно разве что  буквари  по АСУ ТП насоветовать.

Comment: расходомеры крона, пьезометрический трубки, цифровые датчики концентрации. 
Расстояния варьируются от 10 до 100 м
Технологических сетей нет
Букварь есть

Comment: вы понимаете стоймость промышленных решений по автоматизации? Или хотите на коленке из ардуин все построить?

Comment: именно на коленке, денег много не выделяется

Comment: а кто будет отвечать за сорванный техпроцесс? Сейчас датчики куда включены?